# Animating an SVG clip-path is not working correctly in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, svg, clip-path

I am using an SVG `clipPath` to clip an image. ([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b75896tg/))

In Chrome, the animation is broken. The clipped image is only re-rendered when something else changes (for example when dragging the divider between the boxes in JSFiddle).

**Is there a way to "force" Chrome to re-render the image when the SVG `clipPath` changes?**

HTML:

```
<figure><img src="http://placehold.it/400x400" alt="" /></figure>
<svg width="0" height="0">
    <clipPath id="slideActiveClipPath" clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox">
        <polygon points="0 0, 1 0, 1 1, 0 1"></polygon>
    </clipPath>
</svg>
```

CSS:

```
@keyframes slide {
    from {
        transform: scale(0);
    }
    to {
        transform: scale(1);
    }
}

#slideActiveClipPath polygon {
    animation: slide 1s ease-in-out infinite;
}

figure {
    -webkit-clip-path: url(#slideActiveClipPath);
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: Try using SMIL rather than CSS animation